# The donut's icing is sinking into the bread instead of being on top

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have been following ***Blender Guru's*** **Donut** tutorial and while I was following his speed run in making the icing, this happened:

[image]

Why is this happening and how should I fix it?

Comment: Go back and rewatch the part of the tutorial where he does icing.  He explains what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Too emotional. There was more pleading than there was question! Remember, we are here to help you, so implicitly by coming “here” (to stackexchange.com) you’re already asking for help. No need to do again. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+X the faces where you have the frosting, go into object mode, then paste it as a separate object. After you did that, use these key combinations: G+Z. Then move your cursor up and the frosting should go up with it. If you still have issues you may need to edit your hotkeys in user preferences.

Comment: Thanks guys...:-)